# RxJS - when does forkJoin trigger?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

What would cause individual `subscribe` to trigger, but `forkJoin` to not trigger?

I've sent off a request which triggers `subject.subscribe`, but when I've added it to an array to use with forkJoin, the `forkJoin().subscribe` doesn't run. The result that comes back is an object.

```
    let responses$ = [];
    _.map(items, (item) => {
        let subject = new Subject();
        this.apiService.postRequest("/api/my-endpoint", data).subscribe(subject);
        responses$.push(subject);
        subject.subscribe((res) => { console.log("this triggers") });
    });

    Observable.forkJoin(responses$).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log("this does not trigger");
    });
```

And here is postRequest - I'm not sure I'm doing it right, I wanted to chain it like promises.

```
public postRequest(url: string, data: any) {
    return this.getToken().flatMap((accessToken: Response) => {
        return this.post(url, data, {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken});
        });
}
```

Frankly I just wanted to do something similar to `$q.all` with promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forkJoin` will emit an array containing the last values from each of the observables passed to it. It emits the array when all of the observables have completed.

So each observable passed to it will need to emit at least one value and will also need to complete.

The reason your subscription to the joined observable does not trigger is most likely because the observables are not completing. You've not included the implementation of `getToken()` in the question, but unless that observable completes, `forkJoin` will neither emit a value nor complete.

You could ensure that the observables complete by using `first()` in the `postRequest` implementation:

```ts
public postRequest(url: string, data: any) {
  return this.getToken()
    .first()
    .flatMap((accessToken: Response) => {
      return this.post(url, data, {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken});
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I looked into getToken() and I was creating a new Observable but not triggering `onComplete()`.